# Recurring event not showing for the first date in full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

i am trying to display recurring events on the calendar, say like an event that triggers every week day between start and end dates will be displaying event details of that day on weekly view of full calendar 
Eg: event that triggers every sunday between 2019-11-21 00:00:00 to 2019-12-21 12:00:12, so event details are shown on calendar every sunday b/w those period,

[i used the below link to display them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940833/5777188)
so the code that compares the start dates is

> if (theDate <= startDate) {
>         return false;
>       }

so the issue here is the event that start with 2019-11-24 00:00:00 is not displayed on calendar(2019-11-24),instead it displays from next week say like (2019-12-01) ,this works properly if i change the start date to 2019-11-21 00:00:01 am not sure why is it like this and what can i do to start displaying from this very matching date..i.e..2019-11-24 00:00:00

[image: event is not shown for this week]
[image: event is showing for next occurrence]

Comment: please include **your** code and data, not just a link to someone else's. I made a JSFiddle based on the one linked from the answer you linked to, and used your dates. No obvious issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ojkdr6bu/ . So if there's a problem in your version, you need to show your exact code, instead.

Comment: P.S. If I were you, I would seriously consider upgrading to fullCalendar v4, which has [built-in support for recurring events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events)

Comment: thanks for creating the jsfiddle, i added my code thr

Comment: If you saved it, there will be a new link. I cannot see your code unless you provide the new link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2d9z1t6q/4/

Comment: Ok. It's probably to do with timezones, and the start time. But I'm not going to spend ages trying to fix it, because that's just a really ropey implementation of recurring events. There's a much better and more robust implementation for fullCalendar v3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/5947043 . I suggest you use that, or upgrade to v4.